# How do I host a mapbox map on a private network?

Tags: mapbox

I'd like to use mapbox map, 'examples.map-9ijuk24y' on a private network. Can I do this ?
If no, I'm happy to use tilemill to generate my map from my own sources. How do I serve up the .mbtiles from my own server ?

Comment: Is your requirement to self-host the tile server or merely to route the data to your private network? If the latter, a proxy server to route the requests between the internet and your network might suffice...

Answer (score 3):

First, maps under the `examples` account are examples, are watermarked, and they should not be used for production apps.

Second, for maps like that one which are based off of OpenStreetMap, Mapbox's terms are here: https://www.mapbox.com/tos/ While you can download individual tiles and then cache them for an unlimited amount of time, you can't re-serve or proxy them to another network. This would require a custom contract with Mapbox. Please contact support-at-mapbox.com for more info on this.

Last, if you make your own map, say with [TileMill](http://tilemill.com), you are free to do whatever you wish with the resulting MBTiles file. You could upload it to Mapbox (subject to the same terms above) but you could also serve the MBTiles yourself, either with a tile server or directly as a download. A good starting point for making your own worldwide or regional OSM-based map is https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright.